# Redirect to the same page with flash message in AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

So I have two custom authorize attributes: 1) is to redirect the user to login whenever a session has expired or not authenticated; 2) is currently in progress.

The idea for the second custom authorize attribute is to redirect the user to the same page before he/she navigated to the next page or prevent from redirecting to the next page request. Let say the code is

```
public class CustomAuth2Attribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string _errorController = "Error";

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {                        
        var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        var area = "";
        if (filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
            area = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();

        if (controller == _errorController)
        {
            return;
        }


        // checking the user identity whether the user is allowed to access this page
        // then redirect to the previous page before this request and add flash note: "not allowed to access the content"

    }     
}
```

The idea is if the user do not have access to a certain page I do not flag this as not authorize instead I should be returning them to the page they were before with the note message.

Also tried the below code:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
{
    controller,
    action,
    area
}));
```

I'm getting too many redirects which is because I'm referencing the current controller, action, and area instead of the previous one. I also tried getting the UrlReferrer value but this is always `null`.

Any way I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `HandleUnauthorizedResult` for that:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: HandleUnauthorizedRequest is not being triggered even when override

Comment: Are you calling AuthorizeCore? Your onAuthorization is not completetly posted in your question, so this is hard to tell. As a baseline, AuthorizeCore should handle your Authorization logic and you should at least call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)`